# PhoneGap API elements on other platforms, using PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, build

1. I followed the PhoneGap getting started guide for iOS (http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4).
   Then I used the camera function in my project (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera - I used the Full Example). It works well on iPhone.
2. After that I used PhoneGap Build to build my project for other platforms too (https://build.phonegap.com/).
   I downloaded the Android .apk file, but the camera is not working on an Android phone.

I guess the problem might be, that I use the PhoneGap iOS version, as I described in the 1. step, while for Android maybe I should use the Android version of PhoneGap...but I don't know how could I use the PhoneGap for Android js file without having to set up the whole Android development environment (I tought that this is what PhoneGap Build should be used for).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You havent setup the phonegap environment for ANdroid?

Comment: no, because I think that PhoneGap Build should compile it for Android...but the camera is not working. Am I wrong?

Comment: I dont know how the phonegap build works internally... It should work... However i know that in normal phonegap App we need different js files for different platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem :) I simply had to insert the following in the index.html:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

At the moment when I insert this line, the phonegap.js file isn't in the www directory yet, but it will be generated at the moment when it will be built for different platforms. So I didn't had to set up the Android development environment to get the .apk file, which runs on the android phone (I just used PhoneGap Build to get this file).

Comment: would you mind to let me know any additional details? I'm making a phonegap build based application, I added the `script` tag but once I run the application it doesn't works (in my case I'm saving and getting values from local storage, however it doesn't saves them)